# Understanding Crashes & ANRs with Proguard Enabled

Tags: android, logging, crash, proguard, crash-reports

I was taking a look at a crash report on the Developer Console and noticed that, since I have Proguard enabled, all the method names are simply letters. Naturally, this makes debugging the crash rather difficult. I somehow doubt it, but is there anyway to receive crash reports that show the actual method names, while still having Proguard enabled on my app?

Comment: -keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable after this you will know which file and line nuber or http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please, read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html).

> mapping.txt
>       Lists the mapping between the original and obfuscated class, method, and field names. This file is important when you receive a bug
>   report from a release build, because it translates the obfuscated
>   stack trace back to the original class, method, and member names. See
>   Decoding Obfuscated Stack Traces for more information.

And directly [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#decoding).